# how to set up search method in java

Tags: java

I’m new to Java  and I’m trying to make a method called `searchListBySurName` that accepts a String argument and returns true or false depending on whether a name exists with that respective last name.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public boolean searchListBySurName(String SurName)

{
    if (list.contains(SurName)) {

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is the test data I’m using to test the method:

```
public void testSearchListBySurName() {
  r.addName(new Name("Joe", "Bloggs"));
  r.addName(new Name("Fred", "Jones"));

  assertTrue("First search should find Jones, i.e. return true", r.searchListBySurName(new String("Jones")));

  r = new Register();
  r.addName(new Name("Joe", "Bloggs"));
  r.addName(new Name("Fred", "Wayne"));

  assertFalse("Second search should not find Jones, i.e. return false", r.searchListBySurName(new String("Jones")));
}
```

But, the test keeps coming back as failed. What mistake am I making and how can I fix it?

Comment: for more information my array list is called "list"

Comment: Java coding conventions have parameters, variables, and methods start with a lower case letter (surName). Classes start with an upper case letter.

Comment: @pikachu99 would you add the exact error message you're stuck on? For instance, which assert is failing?

Answer (score 5):

Your list is of `Name`, but you search for `String`, so it won't work. The straight-forward way is with a `for` loop:

```
public boolean searchListBySurname(String surname) {
    for (Name name : list)
        if (name.getSurname().equals(surname))
            return true;

    return false;
}
```

Or you could use Java 8 streams:

```
public boolean searchListBySurname(String surname) {
    return list.stream().anyMatch(name -> name.getSurname().equals(surname));
}
```

P.S. Also pay attention to method and parameter names.

Answer (score 0):

It is ok to use `list.contains()` method. But you need to override the `equals` method of `Name` Class.

Using the `List.contains(Object object)` method to determine whether the ArrayList contains an element object (for this case where the SurName value of the Name is the same) should override the `equals()` method. If the `equals()` method in the element Object of `List<E>` is not override, it will cause the `contains()` method to always return false.

```java
@Override  
public boolean equals(Name o) {  
    if (this.SurName = o.SurName){
        return true;
    } else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

In method `searchListBySurName`:

```java
public boolean searchListBySurName(Name name)

{
    if (list.contains(name)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And Use it like this:

```java
public void testSearchListBySurName() {
  r.addName(new Name("Joe", "Bloggs"));
  r.addName(new Name("Fred", "Jones"));

  assertTrue("First search should find Jones, i.e. return true", r.searchListBySurName(new Name("","Jones")));

  r = new Register();
  r.addName(new Name("Joe", "Bloggs"));
  r.addName(new Name("Fred", "Wayne"));

  assertFalse("Second search should not find Jones, i.e. return false", r.searchListBySurName(new Name("","Jones")));
}
```